# Perform actions on DataTemplate's datas when they are completely loaded?

Tags: wpf

I have the itemscontrols in which whose datatemplate is the **"Grid".**

I will dynamically bind the values to that itemscontrol itemsource.

I donot know how much the **itemsource's list count** will be!.

I want to  **perform some actions on the complete set of data**, **after the DataTemplate's data is completely bounded**. (i mean all the grids with its data, are completely loaded).

May i know how to find it?

Ex:

```
<Itemssource itemsource={bindiing listofdata}>
    <datatemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock text={binding name} grid.coulm=0/>
            <TextBlock text={binding age} grid.coulm=1/>
            <TextBlock text={binding address} grid.coulm=2/>
        </Grid>
    </datatemplate>
</Itemsource>
```

**public List < persons> listofdata;**

```
class persons
{
public string name;
public string age;
public string address;
}
```

Now consider **listofdata is having 50 objects of type persons**. It may change at runtime.

Now i want to perform operations on all list of 50 person objects, **after it gets completely loaded into the itemscontrol.** **(Not on the individual person object).**

If i used the **loaded event for the grid, then it will be fired 50 times for each person object**(while loading into the grid).

**I want to fire some event when the list is completely loaded.**

Is there any way to do it??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to understand what you're after, but perhaps the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN will help?

Comment: It's an unusual requirement and hooking the Grid_Loaded event will not work.  Can you explain the sort of action you want to invoke when your list is completely loaded?  Where is the list being generated?

Answer (score 0):

if  you want to check the number of element, you may check it when you are binding it dynamically or if you want to perform some operation on Grid Rows, you may write that in Grid_Loaded Event . you will get all rows there.